# Update initialValues in redux-form asyncronously without using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

The examples in the documentation show only how to update `initialValues` with redux state (see http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/initializeFromState/). I don't want to use redux because it's really messy for the application I'm building. I'd rather use component state.

I've tried using an async self-executing function in the redux-form connector, but that didn't work:

```
ApplicationNewForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'appapp',
    returnRejectedSubmitPromise: true,
    initialValues: (async function() { ... }()),
    handleSubmit
})(ApplicationNewForm)
```

that didn't work (that one should be obvious why, the component doesn't care if the assignment is async...)...

I also tried making the api call in an `async componentDidMount` and using `this.state` to set the `value` prop of my `<Field />`'s.

In each case the values don't seem to make it to the redux store, and so don't update the values in the fields.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:
The solution is to manually call `this.props.initialize` in the `async componentDidMount` with the data from the api call. This *DOES* work:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get('/my/user/api/')
        const { data: user } = res

        this.props.initialize({...user})
    } catch(err) {}
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking I could just use the `change` prop in my form component (see http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Props.md/#-change-field-string-value-any-function-) when the async function is resolved... Will update if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the current version, `v6.5.0`, the `initialValues` config parameter [*takes an object*](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/#-initialvalues-object-string-string-optional-), not an async function. That might be messing with your call to `this.props.initialize()`. Are you seeing the `INITIALIZE` action being dispatched?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was just confused about async/await, that was removed and I now have an object there. This was solved by just using the `initialize` redux-form method and `initialValues` as intended. Please see the EDIT in my post, it _is_ working so maybe I should close this question.

Comment: Yep. I think you can.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the async call. The async function returns a promise right away (which is later fulfilled with the result). You assign this promise to initialValue, and the promise resolution does nothing.

The [docs for ReduxForm](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/initializeFromState/) say that initialValues can only be set once without manually doing an INITIALIZE, so I doubt that using a promise (or redux state update) will do the trick, but I havent used or tried ReduxForm myself so I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about async/await. I'm just learning about generators and such. I found a solution, updated in my question.